# Family or family's?

Tags: possessives

I have a rather silly question that I can not work out the answer for. I've overthought it so much that I seem to have confused myself.

If I am referring to something that belongs to my family would it be the family's? For example, would a planner be the **family's planner**?

And to confuse the matter more, if I was to refer to my family as crazy, would I use **the crazy family's planner**? I've really confused myself. If anybody could help I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Do you mean to use *family* as an adjective to describe the planner:

> What kind of planner is it? It is a *(crazy) family* planner.

Or do you mean to use *family* as a possessive, to show ownership:

> Whose planner is it? It is my *(crazy) family's* planner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't realise my grammar was so bad. I am ordering a family planner for the kitchen wall, the example planner was The Sutton's Family planner. As my family has various surnames we decided to go with us being a crazy family. So i'm guessing i need it to show ownership. Would the crazy family's planner be correct? Thank you.

Comment: "Our (Crazy) Family Planner" will certainly work.